# Code working in c but not in c++

Tags: c++, c

The following code is working fine in C but when I try to write it in c++ then the program does not work.Please explain.

**C code :**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 33,b = 7;
    printf("%d\n",a&b);
    return 0;
}
```

**C++ code:**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 33,b = 7;
    cout << 33&7 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `(33 & 7)`? C++ is a funny ol' language ;p

Comment: Why are you not using the variables `a` and `b` in the C++ case? Confusing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Watch your operator precedence:

```
cout << (33 & 7) << endl;
```

`&` has lower precedence than `<<`. So you need to use `()`.

---

For the full list of operator precedence in C and C++:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Comment: So it shifts `7` by `endl` bits to the left. :)))

Comment: Dammit, it's always "the faster typer the winner" xD Nice answer though.

Comment: `(cout << 33) & (y << endl)` That's awesome. Imagine if it was overloaded in a way to be valid...

Comment: that's why I always put parantheses - even if they are not really necessary. This way the reader of the code does not need to be aware of operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

This question nothing has nothing to do with the difference between  C and C++. This is about the precedence of the operators and deciding where the borders of the expression are. The right example should look like:

```
printf("%d\n", a&b);
```

and

```
short cout;
int endl;
long var = cout << 33 & 7 << endl;
```

The fact, that C++ I/O advises to use `<<` for printing variables is not important. C++ says that the precedence of the overloaded ops is the same as the precedence of regular operators.

Answer (score 1):

Your lines will be explained to:

```
(cout <<33)&(7<<endl);
```

It should be:

```
cout << (33&7) << endl;
```